# How to programmatically manipulate XML trees in IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

Folks, I need some guidance on how to manipulate PSI tree of an XML file in IntelliJ. Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I'm writing a custom action which:

1. finds a list of all XML tags in selection.
2. creates a new XML tag;
3. moves previously selected XML tags to the newly created one.

I was able to implement steps 1 and 2 by finding first and last PsiElements in the selection, finding a parent tag and creating a sublist, as follows:

```
    PsiElement startPsi = psiFile.findElementAt(editor.getSelectionModel().getSelectionStart());
    PsiElement endPsi = psiFile.findElementAt(editor.getSelectionModel().getSelectionEnd());

    XmlTag startTag = null;
    XmlTag endTag = null;

    if (startPsi instanceof XmlTag)
        startTag = (XmlTag)startPsi;
    else
        startTag = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(startPsi, XmlTag.class);
    if (endPsi instanceof XmlTag)
        endTag = (XmlTag)endPsi;
    else
        endTag = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(endPsi, XmlTag.class);

    List<PsiElement> children = Arrays.asList(startTag.getParentTag().getChildren());
    int indexOfStart = children.indexOf(startTag);
    int indexOfEnd = children.indexOf(endTag) + 1;

    List<PsiElement> selectionChildren = children.subList(indexOfStart, indexOfEnd);
```

(I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it).

But where I'm stuck at the moment is moving those children to a new tag. I create the tag as follows:

```
    final XmlTag parentTag = ((XmlFile)psiFile).getRootTag();
    final XmlTag newTag = parentTag.createChildTag("mynewtag", parentTag.getNamespace(), "", false);

    newTag.setAttribute("name", "");
    parentTag.addSubTag(newTag, false);
```

This works, but when I'm trying to add any tags to the newTag, nothing happens. I tried to create a new tag from scratch using the createChildTag() method, or iterating over the list of selectionChildren and calling newTag.addSubTag(), but it doesn't work. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, just can't figure out what is the proper way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to select your text and invoke `Code > Surround with Live Template`?